# VS Projects never execute their post-build events

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c#

Somehow I have disabled post-build events on my VS 2010 install. The same events work fine on other computers and on our build server ... they also work if I invoke MSBuild from the command line.

On my machine using Visual Studio, however, they are never run! I've reinstalled VS2010, but it didn't help.

Can anyone suggest how they could be re-enabled?